# Write tf.float32 Tensor to file

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible in TensorFlow to dump the values of a float32 Tensor to a file ?

The constraints are that 1) eager execution in unavailable and that 2) the Tensor cannot be explicitly evaluated in a session.

I am looking for something similar to tf.Print that would instead append to a file whenever the Tensor is evaluated.

Comment: Why don't you re-direct the output and append it to a file ?? 'SomeCommand >> SomeFile.txt'

Comment: Good question. Personally, I don't find printing tensors to stdout elegant at all, as my app already prints some statistics after each training iteration. This solution would also come with a string parsing step as an overhead.

Comment: You could distinguish the information by re-direct some parts to stderr and some parts to stdout. There are ways of course to write information to a text using tensorflow API but it is more complicated. By doing that, you can also hard-code the parsing and writing operations in the graph, but do you really want to do that?